# awk's range is reset when working with multiple files

Tags: awk, gawk

Let's say I have files `1.txt`, `2.txt` and `3.txt`, all with the following contents respectively:

```
foo1

Notes

foo2
bar
```

Now, I want to print out lines, which are placed **after** the pattern `Notes` till the end of file, and contain either `foo` or `bar` patterns. To achieve that I run the following:

```
awk '/Notes/,/getline==0/ {if (/foo|bar/) {print}}' *txt
```

However, this range seems to be reset as soon as `awk` proceeds with the second file, since the result is the following (only `foo2` and `bar` entries should be displayed):

```
foo2
bar
foo1
foo2
bar
foo1
foo2
bar
```

Obviously, if I do something like this:

```
for i in $(*txt); do awk '/Notes/,/getline==0/ {if (/foo|bar/) {print}}' $i; done
```

...everything will be sort of ok, but, of course, I don't want to start a new `awk` process for each file, so that's not really a solution.

My question is, how to tell `awk` to apply this search range `/Notes/,/NR==0/` to all the files in a `*txt` mask/group?

Comment: `/getline==0/` is searching for the *pattern* `getline==0` - which never occurs

Comment: @steeldriver, OK, but how do I define such range then?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`/getline==0/` is searching for the *pattern* `getline==0`, which never occurs.

If you have GNU awk, you could do

```
gawk '/Notes/{notes=1} notes && /foo|bar/ {print} ENDFILE{notes=0}'
```

Otherwise (and more idiomatically)

```
awk 'FNR==1{notes=0} /Notes/{notes=1} notes && /foo|bar/'
```

Comment: Thanks, it works! I even knew this trick with setting a temp var at a pattern but was too stupid to apply it here :)